# WP8/VS2012 - Viewing a list variable in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, binding, longlistselector

I'm very new to programming in Visual Studio and for Windows Phone 8. I do have knowledge in PHP, so I understand the basics of syntax, albeit a slight differentiation from C#, however.

Anyways, I am simply trying to make a list I've declared in a variable in \MainPage.xaml.cs viewable in \MainPage.xaml, via binding, I guess that's how it's done.

I'm trying to make it as basic as possible for now; here is what I have in the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using lbpme_viewer.Resources;

namespace lbpme_viewer
{

    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        List<String> MenuItems = new List<String> { "portal", "news", "myprofile", "settings" };

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

And I would just make 4 plain textblocks, but I want to remove "myprofile" based on the user's settings, but before I get to that, right now I just declared them all in one list of strings.

And a portion of my XAML file:

```
        <!--Panorama item one-->
    <phone:PanoramaItem Header="first item">
        <!--Single line list with text wrapping-->
        <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="menuList" Margin="0,0,-22,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,-6,0,12">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
    </phone:PanoramaItem>
```

And obviously the items won't show in the LongListSelector. I don't expect them to because I know I'm missing one or many pieces of code required to do so, and my question is, how?

Again, I just want the list of phrases in the MenuList variable to appear in my LongListSelector, like how "design one" "design two" does in the default panorama/pivot app upon creation.

And if it wouldn't be much different, how would I get any variable from the C# code to appear in the XAML file?

Thank you!

Comment: Edited your question -- it's Visual *Studio* (an IDE), not Visual *Basic* (a programming language).

Answer (score 0):

Try binding to an `ObservableCollection<string>` that implements INotifyPropertyChanged like this

```
List<String> MenuItemsList = new List<String> { "portal", "news", "myprofile", "settings" };

private ObservableCollection<string> _menuItems;
public ObservableCollection<string> MenuItems
{
    get { return _menuItems; }
    set
    {
        if (_menuItems == value) return;
        _menuItems = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(); // or NotifyPropertyChanged("MenuItems");
    }
}
```

then in your constructor new up the ObservableCollection by passing in the List

```
MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<string>(MenuItemsList);
```

You also need this in your class (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
// This method is called by the Set accessor of each property. 
// The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName 
// parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument. 
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Take a look at MVVM Light, it makes a lot of WPF things easier. With MVVM Light, your property could look like this (and you wouldn't need all the NotifyPropertyChanged stuff)

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _menuItems;
public ObservableCollection<string> MenuItems
{
    get { return _menuItems; }
    set
    {
        if (_menuItems == value) return;
        _menuItems = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => MenuItems);
    }
}
```

Comment: ObservationCollection cannot be found? Also how do I add what's in the link to my class, what exactly would that be doing and in what file? Sorry but this is really confusing me. :/

Comment: Try adding the namepspace;  using System.Collections.ObjectModel;